# How to print matched regex pattern using awk svr08-core1-1654761552.278?

Tags: regex, awk

How to print matched regex pattern using awk?

How to print `svr08-core1-1654761552.278` columns?

My log files

```
"/usr/local/bin/publisher calllog -account='IE-00683' -uniqueid='svr08-core1-1654762416.510' -linkedid='svr08-core1-1654762416.510' -channel='SIP/IE-00683-72-000001f8' -sipcallid='3382826129@192_168_2_61' -originalsipcallid='3382826129@192_168_2_61' -src_ext='72' -dst_ext='44' -call_direction='internal' >>/var/log/asterisk/publisher_asterisk.log 2>&1 &") in new stack
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I suggest to use `sed` for this job.

Comment: "My log files" does not contain the string you ask for. How are you defining "columns"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n "s/.*\-uniqueid='\([[:alnum:]\.-]\{1,\}\)'.*/\1/p" file.log
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to include more details and/or example input and the corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 1):

> How to print matched regex pattern using awk?

[`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function sets `RSTART` to start of match or `0` if not match found and `RLENGTH` to length of match or `-1` if not match found. RSTART value is also return value. Variables set can be used with `substr` to get matched string, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
abc 123 def
7 ghi 8
nodigitshere
```

then

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+/){print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
123
7
```

Explanation: `match` function is used, return of which is true if match found and false otherwise, when considering as boolean. I instruct GNU `AWK` to look for 1 or more (`+`) digits (`[0-9]`) in whole line (`$0`). If there is match I `print` substring of whole line (`$0`) starting at start of match and of length of match. Note that if line contain more 1 substring matching regex leftmost one (first) will be printed as seen in 2nd line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*